# Why torch.dot(a,b) makes requires_grad=False

Tags: pytorch

I have some losses in a loop storing them in a tensor `loss`. Now I want to multiply a weight tensor to the loss tensor to have final loss, but after `torch.dot()`, the result scalar, `ll_new`, has `requires_grad=False`. The following is my code.

```py
loss_vector = torch.FloatTensor(total_loss_q)
w_norm = F.softmax(loss_vector, dim=0)
ll_new = torch.dot(loss_vector,w_norm)
```

How can I have `requires_grad=False` for the `ll_new` after doing the above?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is in the line: `loss_vector = torch.FloatTensor(total_loss_q)` as `requires_grad` for `loss_vector` is False (default value). So, you should do:

```
loss_vector = torch.FloatTensor(total_loss_q, requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: This is kind of a strange answer from my point of view: first of all, it doesn't seem that `torch.FloatTensor` is actually accepting `requires_grad` argument at all. But even if it did - what would you expect from this? New tensor generated from non-tensor object would not help to propagate gradients to the trainable weights which were used to create these losses, right?

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely lies within this part:

> I have some losses in a loop storing them in a tensor `loss`

You are most likely losing `requires_grad` somewhere in the process before `torch.dot`. E.g. if you use something like `.item()` on individual losses when constructing `total_loss_q` tensor.

What type is your `total_loss_q`? If it is a list of integers then there is no way your gradients will propagate through that. You need to construct `total_loss_q` in such a way that it is a tensor which knows how each individual loss was constructed (i.e. can propagate gradients to your trainable weights).